# "Computers & Security" journal latex template?

Tags: journals, computer-science, formatting, latex

The following links explains the "Guide for Authors" for the "Computers & Security" journal:

https://www.elsevier.com/journals/computers-and-security/0167-4048/guide-for-authors

However, I cannot find a latex template for this journal. Does it mean that I can write the paper in any template format ?

Here is an example of a paper that is published in Computers & Security" journal. However, I need a latex template:

[Example Paper in PDF](https://s3.amazonaws.com/academia.edu.documents/43666396/On_the_Limits_of_Engine_Analysis_for_Che20160312-26856-1nvy2l5.pdf?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIWOWYYGZ2Y53UL3A&Expires=1531667434&Signature=xqiy6Cw8DY3l8lqjwPwrhy81g1A%3D&response-content-disposition=inline%3B%20filename%3DOn_the_limits_of_engine_analysis_for_che.pdf)

Comment: Worth asking Elsevier?

Comment: @Solar Mike There is a latex template in sharelatex HERE: https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/journals/elsevier , however its format seems to be different with PDF example. I'm going to ask elsivier by email. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following the various links of the Guide for Authors one arrives at the [LaTeX Instructions page](https://www.elsevier.com/authors/author-schemas/latex-instructions) of Elsevier, which recommends the usage of the class [`elsarticle`](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/elsarticle).

Comment: Thank you, so this template should be acceptable ? [link](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/journals/elsevier)